# Why is this simple 3 line program not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Pract:
    p1 = Pract()  #creating an instance of Pract
    p1.age=45     #creating a field-variable
print(p1.age)
```

I checked this Youtube, in the video its shows as working, but I couldn't run it.

Comment: (1) Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361) (2) What exactly is "not working"? What's the error message?

Comment: That's not how classes work. Not even close. What are you trying to do, really?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: i was getting an error message  "Pract not defined", but got the answer anyway. The above code worked with some modifications,  I missed the pass statement & indentation, (as I watched on Youtube). Beginner, apologies. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# First declare a class (empty, in this case)
class Pract:
    pass

# Then instantiate it
p1 = Pract()
# Then set the attribute
p1.age = 45
# Then print the attribute
print(p1.age)
```

You cannot instantiate a class *before* you finish declaring it. Everything you put inside `class` is part of the class definition. You have to de-indent your code in order to mark the end of the class definition.

Comment: Thanks Andrea..as I said I'm very beginner. Thanks for helping. In the video it didn't show writing 'pass'. so missed it. Thanks